# Getting null value in ajax post request

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-ajax, ajax.beginform

Every time when I run the project in different way all the time I got the success result null:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code in the question itself?

Comment: In your C# code is a property called PurchaseOrderNo in your JSON it's called PurchaseOrderId.

Comment: PurchaseOrderNo is a property of PurchaseOrder class and PurchaseOrderId  is a parameter, the twist is I get success result in ajax request but it null.

Comment: Looks like the problem is not the ajax, but InformationUpdate must be returning null. Can't help with that.